# PHP loop and return $key of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm trying to write a PHP function to loop into a multidimensional array to match it with a business name then return to me the "business type".

With my current skills, I wrote this function but I would like to know if there's a better solution other than looping twice because my real arrays are much bigger than the example below.

Note: I'm a student, I already searched StackOverflow but couldn't find my need.

```
function find_business_type($dealer_name) {
    $business_type = [
        "OEM"               => ["kia", "mercedes"],
        "Rent"              => ["rent", "rent-a-car"],
        "Workshop"          => ["shop", "workshop"],
        "Spare Parts"       => ["spare", "parts", "part"],
        "General Trading"   => ["gen", "general"]
    ];

    foreach ($business_type as $key => $values) {
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            if (strpos($dealer_name, $value) !== false) {
                return $key;
            }
        }
    }
}


$my_dealer = "super-stars-123 rent a car";
echo find_business_type($my_dealer);
```

> Output: "Rent"

Comment: This will fall apart when a dealer name contains key-words from multiple business types. You'd better add the key to an array, complete all loops and then return the generated array.

Comment: In this case your output want to be Rent right?

Comment: Yes, output, in this case, is "Rent".

Comment: I got your output correctly

Comment: @jeroen doesn't the PHP `foreach` loop stops when a `return` is found? So once I have a match the loop will stop.

Comment: What do you want now

Comment: I agree with @jeroen. If you can possibly match the names exactly you can use `in_array()`: [see here](https://3v4l.org/BnWFW). That will be a little more performant.

Comment: @Salam That is exactly the problem, you will end up with 1 business type while the name actually matches various.

Comment: @Nawin , I was asking if there's a better way other than looping inside a loop, because my arrays are big.

Comment: If your code works as expected but might be optimized you should look at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get some tips on improving it. That might be the better pace in your case.

Comment: @ishegg your solutions work only if my dealer name exactly matches one of my sub-array elements.

Comment: to demonstrate what jeroen means: assume your dealer name is `mercedes rent a car`. your function will return "OEM" because it is the first match. But what about "Rent"? it would also have matched. That is why jeroen suggests returning an array that contains "OEM" **and** "Rent"

Comment: Rebuild the array to a new array, use the `dealer_name` as key and value is an array of `business_type`. After that you do not need any loop for all `business_type` of a `dealer_name` .

Comment: @Cashbee , I got it, that's a loophole caused by my dealer names and I will fix it, but still **my question is there a better way/function other than looping inside a loop?**

Comment: not if `$values` is an array. If you let each business_type have a key and **one** value only, you could do it with only one foreach loop.

Comment: Well actually you could use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) on your $values where you check for each value if the dealer name contains the value. It will still kind of be an iteration within a foreach loop, but I think it should be quite a bit faster

Comment: @Salam the only reliable way to improve the performance is to convert your `$business_type` into some structure that can be searched faster. And there are many ways to do that but in the end it cost more performance to do that if you have to do it with every search process, so you have to cache it or use a special data base depending on the size of your data and how often it changes it might not be worth so much effort. Because it will get far more complicated. Still I suggest asking the question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). :)

Comment: @xander I don't think I know how to cache it and it doesn't worth a database. I would post it on Code Review but my account is new and I can't post more than once per hour. Again I'm student and thanks for your comments, all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea. Essentially, you can filter the array and grab all the rows that match your string based on a percent. Note that [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will return an array with all the matching values not just one match.

```
    <?php

$dealer = "super-stars-123 rent a car";

$types = [
        "OEM"               => ["kia", "mercedes"],
        "Stars"             => ["super-stars", "123"],
        "Brown"             => ["super stars", "abc"],
        "Home"              => ["think rent", "123"],
        "Super"             => ["renter", "car"],
        "Rent"              => ["rent", "rent-a-car"],
        "Workshop"          => ["shop", "workshop"],
        "Spare Parts"       => ["spare", "parts", "part"],
        "General Trading"   => ["gen", "general"]
    ];

// Filter through your array
$results = array_filter($types, function($type) use ($dealer) {
    // explode your inner array to a string and then try to match it
    // to your search dealer text. This returns a % match.
    // I would play around with this algo logic below to get it to do what you want.
    return (similar_text($dealer, implode(", ",$type), $percent) >= 8);
});

var_dump($results);   

 array (size=4)
  'Stars' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'super-stars' (length=11)
      1 => string '123' (length=3)
  'Brown' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'super stars' (length=11)
      1 => string 'abc' (length=3)
  'Super' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'renter' (length=6)
      1 => string 'car' (length=3)
  'Rent' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'rent' (length=4)
      1 => string 'rent-a-car' (length=10)
```

Comment: I like `similar_text` but maybe there's a better way to use `strpos` the way you did in your question.